# Convert Y-axis to Z-axis for export from Unity to 3ds max

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, axis

I need to convert animation from Unity to 3ds max, but there are different coordinate systems.

I wrote a method. Where I made a mistake? Please help

```
public static Quaternion ConvertRotation(Vector3 rotation) {
    Vector3 flip = new Vector3(rotation.z, -rotation.x, -rotation.y);
        Quaternion qx = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flip.x, Vector3.left);
        Quaternion qy = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flip.y, Vector3.forward);
        Quaternion qz = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flip.z, Vector3.up);
        Quaternion qq = qx * qy * qz;
        return qq;
}
```

Comment: I thought all you needed to do in 3ds max was rotate 90° along the X axis and set Y as up. Also you should describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve and why your code isn't working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76107749/converting-euler-rotation-angles-from-z-up-to-y-up-max-to-maya/76127305#76127305 
The coordinate systems are the same.